# IAM Identity Center: Cannot see S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have just created an S3 bucket ato host some PDFs that will be publicly accessible. That is all working fine.

The PDFs need to be updated regularly so I want to create a separate account so other non-IT users can update them without bothering me.

I have created a user in IAM Identity Center who will be allowed to upload to this bucket and nothing else.

I have created this permission set and which is assigned to that user:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bicketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I log in as that user I see "No buckets" in S3.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please note that **IAM Identity Center** is used to link users to AWS via SSO. It is different to "IAM". Did you specifically want to create an SSO user?

Comment: Are you saying that if you login normally and go to the S3 Management Console, you can see a list of buckets, but if you login as this user and go to the same page, it is an empty list? Or are there some error messages appearing? Are you sure it is logging into the same AWS Account (you can check the account number in the name pull-down in the top-right)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the user you created does not have the necessary permissions to view the S3 bucket. To grant the user the necessary permissions, you can add an additional statement to the bucket policy that allows the s3:ListBucket action for the specific bucket:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/USERNAME"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above policy, replace **ACCOUNT_ID** with your AWS account ID and **USERNAME** with the name of the user you created.

Also, make sure that the user has permission to access S3 resources. You can attach the policy you mentioned in the question to the user, or you can create a group and add the user to the group. Then, attach the policy to the group.

After making these changes, the user should be able to see the S3 bucket when they log in.

Comment: Permissions on the User should be sufficient without needing a Bucket Policy.